# Why is Chrome not displaying my @font-face?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-face

I am loading a Hello World html file in Chrome 95, with a declared @font-face loaded from Google fonts. The font is correctly loading, which I can verify in the Network tab, but for some reason my div is rendering as Times.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<div style='font-family:OpenSans-Regular;'>
    Hello World!
</div>
</html>
<style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-stretch: 100%;
      font-display: swap;
      src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v27/memvYaGs126MiZpBA-UvWbX2vVnXBbObj2OVTSKmu0SC55K5gw.woff2) format('woff2');
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Google fonts document](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started), you should use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Font+Name">` instead of write them directly.

Your `<style>` element are in wrong place, there are no `<body>` element in your HTML.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">

        <style>
            * {
                font-family: "Open Sans";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='font-family:Open Sans'>
            Hello World!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```